# Android fragment isn't added after screen rotation

Tags: android, android-fragments

I use fragment without any layout (it downloads file in background). 
I add it once when activity is created in first time assuming that it will be attached again after screen orientation, but it isn't!
Activity onCreate:

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(new FragmentDownloadApp(), FragmentDownloadApp.TAG)
            .commit();
} else {
    if (savedInstanceState.containsKey(STATE_SELECTED_NAVIGATION_ITEM)) {
```

Fragment onActivityCreated:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    // this is really important in order to save the state across screen
    // configuration changes for example
    setRetainInstance(true);

    // ---- magic lines starting here -----
    // call this to re-connect with an existing
    // loader (after screen configuration changes for e.g!)
    LoaderManager lm = getLoaderManager();
    if (lm.getLoader(LOADER_DOWNLOAD_APP) != null) {
        lm.initLoader(LOADER_DOWNLOAD_APP, null, mDownLoader);
    }
    // ----- end magic lines -----
}
```

And error:

```
public void onPositiveClick() {
            FragmentDownloadApp fragment = (FragmentDownloadApp) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentByTag(FragmentDownloadApp.TAG);
            fragment.startDownload(mAppToDownload);
        }
```

Here appears NullPointerException!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found answer:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState); // NEED THIS!
```